# Create new array when button is pressed

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, uikit

I want to create a new array every time when a button (ActionButton) is pressed. When this button is pressed the first time then a new array should be created and 10 should be added. When the button is pressed the second time then another new array should be created and add 20. And so on. I would like to also save the created arrays in Core Data.
In this case the named error occured. But when change from `let` to `var` then it is only 1 array and it will be overwritten every time right?
Could you be so kind and show me which code is right to create a new array, add the current value, and save it.

```swift
import UIKit
import CoreData

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var number : Double = 0
    
    //  Reference to Managed Object Context
    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as!     AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    var average : Stats?
    var array : Stats?
    
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        fetchStats()
        
    }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    @IBAction func ActionButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        number += 10.0
        average?.value = number
        
        //Idea
        let newarray = [Double]()
        newarray.append(number)
        array?.new = newarray
        
        //Error message by .append:
            //Cannot use mutatingChange 'let' to 'var' to make it mutable member on                                            immutable value: 'TestArray' is a 'let' constant
            //Change 'let' to 'var' to make it mutable
        
        
        saveData()
    
    }
    
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    func fetchStats() {
        
    //Fetch the data from CoreData to display in the View
    do {
        if let found = try context.fetch(Stats.fetchRequest()).first {
            average = found
            number = found.value
            
            array = found
            newarray = found.new
            
        } else {
            average = Stats(context: context)
            average?.value = 0
            
            array = Stats(context: context)
            array?.new = []
            
            saveData()
        }
                    
    }
    catch {
        print(error)
        }
    }
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    func saveData() {
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a comment. `ActionButton` here is not the button but is the function called when the button is tapped and should start with a lowercase letter. Something like `actionButtonTapped` would be a good name for it.

Comment: You can't append to the `newarray` because it is a `let`. I'm not sure what your comment about using `var` is referring to? But if you want to add to the `newarray` then it needs to be a `var` not a `let`.

Comment: Having said that... your `newarray` will only ever contain a single value. Can you explain what you're trying to do in general and I can perhaps help with that.

Comment: Please do not add the Xcode tag. Your question is not asking about the functionality of Xcode.

Comment: @Fogmeister In general I´m trying to create a new array each time when the ActionButton is tapped. In this new array the current value should be append. First tapp = [10] second tapp = [20] third tapp = [30] and so on. This arrays shall be saved in CoreData. 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Fogmeister To be more precise the output shall be: newarray1 = [10] newarray2 = [20] newarray3 = [30] and so on.

Comment: @MarcS. In that case you can just do `let newArray = [number]`

Comment: @Fogmeister thank you for the tip. Is the below question possible? (With this 2 Arrays)

Comment: @MarcS. that will work but I question what you're doing. It's a VERY odd thing to want to do. Can you perhaps try to explain what this feature of your app is doing. I feel like there will be a much better way of doing it.

Comment: @Fogmeister the feature of my app will be: calculate the averages over the whole year and save in the first array, let's say "Array0". When a new year started I want to create a new array "Array1" and append the averages from the current year. I would like also show this different arrays in a chart. But Array0 in chart1 and Array1 in chart2.
I thought to pass the arrays to the graph, it is easier to generate every year a new array or is there an easier solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear why you want multiple single-element arrays, but assuming you have a valid reason...

You want to use an "**array of arrays**". With each button tap, you will append a new array to the "array of arrays":

```
class ViewContoller: UIViewController {
    
    var number : Double = 0
    var theArrays: [[Double]] = []
    
    @IBAction func ActionButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        number += 10.0
        theArrays.append([number])
        
        print() // blank line

        for i in 0..<theArrays.count {
            print("Array \(i):", theArrays[i])
        }

        print() // blank line

        print("theArrays:", theArrays)

        print() // blank line
        print("-----------")
    }

}
```

If you tap the button 4 times, this is what you'll see in the debug console:

```
Array 0: [10.0]

theArrays: [[10.0]]

-----------

Array 0: [10.0]
Array 1: [20.0]

theArrays: [[10.0], [20.0]]

-----------

Array 0: [10.0]
Array 1: [20.0]
Array 2: [30.0]

theArrays: [[10.0], [20.0], [30.0]]

-----------

Array 0: [10.0]
Array 1: [20.0]
Array 2: [30.0]
Array 3: [40.0]

theArrays: [[10.0], [20.0], [30.0], [40.0]]

-----------
```

---

**Edit** - *to answer comment...*

If you want to add 5 numbers to each "sub-array" we can add a `currentIndex` property to track the sub-arrays within the "main" array.

When we've appended 5 numbers to the array at currentIndex, we will increment currentIndex and append a new, empty array to the "main" array.

```
class ViewContoller: UIViewController {
    
    var number : Double = 0
    var theArrays: [[Double]] = []
    
    // to track which sub-array we're appending new numbers to
    var currentIndex: Int = 0
    
    @IBAction func ActionButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        number += 10.0
        
        // if theArrays is empty
        if theArrays.isEmpty {
            // that means this is the very first time button was tapped
            //  so append an empty array to theArrays
            theArrays.append([])
            // set currentIndex to Zero, in case
            //  it has been changed somewhere else
            currentIndex = 0
        }

        // if the array at currentIndex has 5 elements
        if theArrays[currentIndex].count == 5 {
            // increment currentIndex
            currentIndex += 1
            // append an empty array to theArrays
            theArrays.append([])
        }
        
        // append number to the array at currentIndex
        theArrays[currentIndex].append(number)
        
        print() // blank line
        
        for i in 0..<theArrays.count {
            print("Array \(i):", theArrays[i])
        }

        print() // blank line

        print("theArrays:", theArrays)

        print() // blank line
        print("-----------")
    }

}
```

Now, after tapping 27 times, we'll see this in the debug console:

```
-----------

Array 0: [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0]
Array 1: [60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0, 100.0]
Array 2: [110.0, 120.0, 130.0, 140.0, 150.0]
Array 3: [160.0, 170.0, 180.0, 190.0, 200.0]
Array 4: [210.0, 220.0, 230.0, 240.0, 250.0]
Array 5: [260.0, 270.0]

theArrays: [[10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0], [60.0, 70.0, 80.0, 90.0, 100.0], [110.0, 120.0, 130.0, 140.0, 150.0], [160.0, 170.0, 180.0, 190.0, 200.0], [210.0, 220.0, 230.0, 240.0, 250.0], [260.0, 270.0]]

-----------
```

Comment: thank you for the explanations and the code.
Is the following possible?: 
The first time when the button is pressed then a new array will be created with the number: Array0: [10.0] To press 4 more times then the numbers will be append to the Array0: [10.0, 20.0, 30.0, 40.0, 50.0].
When pressed the six time then a new Array1 will be created with the number: Array1: [60.0]
But with "let" Array the .append is not possible and I get the named error.

Comment: @MarcS. - see the **Edit** to my answer.

Comment: thank you very much, your code and the explanations helped me a lot.